# jQuery: if redirected from

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to execute a function in jQuery only if the visitor has been redirected from a specific URL. I'm having a ton of trouble making it work. Does anyone know if this is possible? Thanks so much! I've tried...

```
if (location.href === 'http://l.ead.me/bayWpx'){
jQuery('.x-img-link').click();
}
```

and

```
 if (document.referrer.indexOf('http://l.ead.me/bayWpx') >= 0){
 jQuery('.x-img-link').click();
 }
```

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want

```
if (document.referrer == 'http://l.ead.me/bayWpx'){
  jQuery('.x-img-link').click();
}
```

`location.href` tells the browser to go to a URL.

Answer (score 0):

Do somethings like

```js
if(document.referrer == 'http://specific.url'){
    //Action
    jQuery('.x-img-link').trigger('click');//by exemple
}
```